# Linux JNI unsatisfied link error: found the lib but can't bind to function points

Tags: linux, java-native-interface, clion

The System.load found the shared libary, but now it looks like the signatures for the function calls are wrong.

Main class:

```
package java_main;

/**
 *
 * @author james
 */
public class Main {
    static {
        System.out.println("static one");
        System.load("/home/james/Desktop/NewApiWork_scratch/build/Debug/libmodule.so");
        System.out.println("static two");
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main ma = new Main();
        System.out.println("public static void main(String[] args)");
        try
        {
            ma.MAIN();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            if (e.getCause() != null)
            {
                System.out.printf("Cause: %s\n", e.getCause().toString());
            }
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
    public native void MAIN();

}
```

main.c file:

```
//
// Created by James on 8/30/2015.
//

#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Class:     java_main_Main
 * Method:    MAIN
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL _Java_java_1main_Main_MAIN
        (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    puts("Java_java_1main_Main_MAIN");

}
```

Launch and output:

```
   /usr/bin/java -Djava.library.path=./build/Debug -cp .:javastubs_16 java_main.Main
    static one
    static two
    public static void main(String[] args)
    java_main.Main.MAIN()V
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: java_main.Main.MAIN()V
        at java_main.Main.MAIN(Native Method)
        at java_main.Main.main(Main.java:27)
```

I'm using CLion on Linux.

I at a loss at what's going on. 
I'll add more to the question as I get more feedback.

**UPDATE**

It's the leading underscore on the identifiers.  In windows, Java don't recognize stdcall correctly, and you have to add a leading underscore to exported functions.  All I do is remove the leading underscore.

**UPDATE TO THE UPDATE**

It's probably mingw thing not Java.  I dealt with this a while back, and I can't remember the responsible party.

Comment: And how do I edit the question.

Comment: I've been able to make edits through my cell phone.

Comment: just found the edit hyper links